# How to route Button events from a WPF application to a wcf service

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I have a wcf service hosted in a wpf application. I also have a multiple remote clients which are communicating with the service without any problems.

I want to know how to get hold of the service instance from WPF application.

I'm trying to use the `IClientCallback` returned from `OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<IClientCallback>()` 
to make a call to the operations on the client side when a button is pressed in the WPF application.

The `InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single` on the service side if this helps. Please show me through a code example as I'm new to WCF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by myself. I had to use the one of the overloaded constructors of servicehost and pass in the class holding the data contracts.

```
public ServiceHost(
object singletonInstance,
params Uri[] baseAddresses
```